# Регулярное выражение. Получить значение из тега

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Привет, я пишу парсер для сайта. Мне нужно вытащить данные оттуда. Есть html вида:

        
            
            Ст.
            Адрес

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="box0" value="1066" onclick="add(0)"></td>
        <td>Б<!-- <select name='side0'disabled>Б</select> --></td>
        <td id="0" name="0"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('/address/html/6x3/0/1066/','_blank','width=820, height=320,top=100,left=100'); return false;">1-й Муринский проспект/ Лесной проспект (от площади Мужества к ст. м. =Лесная=)</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Мну нужно из этих данных вытащить 3 строку(из кода) и чтобы в массив записалось только буква(пример - Array ( [0] => Б [1] => Б )).

Как написать такое регулярное выражение?
Вот это регулярное выражение достает все из тега td - preg_match ( '~td(.*)/td~is', $str , $matches);

Comment: Не используйте регулярки для парсинга HTML. Возьмите нормальный готовый парсер HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет!

```
<?php
$str = '    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="box0" value="1066" onclick="add(0)"></td>
    <td>Б<!-- <select name=\'side0\'disabled>Б</select> --></td>
    <td id="0" name="0"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open(\'/address/html/6x3/0/1066/\',\'_blank\',\'width=820, height=320,top=100,left=100\'); return false;">1-й Муринский проспект/ Лесной проспект (от площади Мужества к ст. м. =Лесная=)</a></td>
</tr>';

preg_match('/<td>([А-яЁё])/u',$str,$result);

var_dump($result);
```

https://phpbox.info/EkA2V

Comment: u - если парсите строку в UTF-8

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я тоже уже написал. Вот моя версия - preg_match ( '~<td>([А-Б][^<])~is', $str , $matches);

Answer (score 2):

Зачем использовать регулярные выражения для парсинга `HTML` кода? Почему бы не использовать, например, [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

```
<?php
$html = '
    <tr>
        <td>А</td>
        <td>Б</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
';  // HTML код

include('simple_html_dom.php');  // Подключение PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
$doc = new simple_html_dom();  // Создание объекта
$doc->load($html);  // Загрузка из строки
$elemets = $doc->find("td");  // Поиск всех столбцов

echo $elemets[1]->innertext();  //Вывод 'Б' на экран
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже написал. Мне не нужны сторонние библиотеки! 
preg_match ( '~<td>([А-Б][^<])~is', $str , $matches);

Comment: @АртурАтласов, тогда используйте [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php).